# Can i create custom touch events for iPhone

Tags: iphone, multi-touch

Can i create custom touch events for iPhone?? will the device support for creating my own touch event handling ?

Comment: you should explain what you're trying to do. Maybe give an example.

Comment: i want to rotate an image with custom touch event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the UIResponder class:
http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You will probably want to implement the `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesEnded:withEvent:` and `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` methods. These will all be called with an NSSet of UITouches that you can do whatever you want with.

Answer (score 0):

As of the 3.2 SDK there are UIGestureRecognizer classess.  They do not play well with the older UIResponder calls, but if you can do 3.2 only they are easier to get going.

There are a number of handy subclasses, such as UIRotationGestureRecognizer for handling rotation.

If you are extending Apple classes like UIScrollView you must use gesture recognizers with 3.2 and later because when a gesture recognizer cancels it will cancel your UIResponder call tracking as well.  If you are handling all the gesture tracking this is not an issue.